# How to load only specific `defun`s of a emacs lisp file, and not the entire file?

Tags: load

I want to use only only the `custom-value-satisfies-type-p` and `custom-type` functions of [this file](https://github.com/emacsmirror/cus-edit-plus/blob/99b16cb95e1b892e15e3091f124e0be6dd914e16/cus-edit%2B.el) , but if I `load` the file, it will execute some `def-advice`s and `defun`overrides I do not want happening.

**Is there some mechanism for loading only those functions?**

I'm ok with forking and doing some "light" modification of the source; "light" can mean adding something like a `;;;###load-only` magic comment (if that exists), but "light" *cannot* mean deleting all other code in the source, as at that point it would cause too many merge conflicts when I pulled in updates and I would be better off just copy-pasting those function definitions into my config as I am currently doing.

---

Why I want these two functions: combining them is the closest (but still very far) thing I found to having "static" type checking in emacs lisp. It is closer to "static" because it lets me get type errors at declaration time instead of at utilization time, and avoid cases where functions will suppress type errors by becoming no-ops.

Comment: How about write your own code/function to read the file content one sexp at a time. Eval that sexp if and only if its car is defun and its cadr is the name of the functions you desire.

Comment: @TerryTsao that could work, thanks. Feel free to add it as the answer; I'll accept it.